# Hibernate select (JpaRepository dynamic find) fails due to previously attempted (but not persisted) bad insert

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I have a Service class that has a reference to a JpaRepository.

```
@Autowired
private MyRepository MyRepository;
```

MyRepository is defined as

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, String>
{
    List<MyObject> findMyObjectByThisIdAndThatId(String thisId, String thatId);
    // other other find method
}
```

My code is in a loop of a custom Spring Batch Writer that does some processing on some pre-read data, and then saves instances of MyObject.

The relevant pseudo-loop is:

```
for each dataset containing data for new/updated MyObject
    1. query DB for existing instance of MyObject by uniquely identifying data
    2. create new MyObject instance or modify returned MyObject instance
    3. `JpaRepository.save(MyObject)` (could be insert or update)
```

I have some garbage in the very 1st dataset, that causes an attempt to write to the database (#4) data that is bad, namely a 2-char state field that is getting the value "State". (This will be fixed but not yet because a save failure is a possibility so the code needs to handle it.)

Obviously the DB does not like this. However, the JpaRepository.save (or saveAndFlush) seems to return without pushing to the DB.

When I get back to the top of the look and run #2 again, that **DB** query fails with the exception I should have gotten on the previous loop iteration.

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Batch, MySQL, JPA (and JdbcTemplate, which is used in parts of the loop, but not in this read/write). Tomcat is only running because I need Actuator.

I have `spring.datasource.auto-commit=true` in application.properties.

For some reason the save is not going to the DB until the subsequent read.

But the weirdest thing is that for every subsequent loop iteration, the read fails with an exception on the same data. So for some reason the "transaction" (used loosely as I am not using Transactions) is buffered, and after the first bad save, the failure is never flushed out and is continuously returned to all subsequent reads.

Please help!!! How do I fix this?! I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

**NEW INFO**
It seems that during my `find` method call, `SessionImpl.list()` invokes `SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired()` which indirectly attempts to execute and flush all unexecuted transactions. `EntityInsertAction` is not getting recreated here (since it is an old EntityInsertAction being re-executed) so the same insert exception is thrown for every subsequent select.

How do I get a failed insert to get discarded so that subsequent operations are not at the mercy of the state of the previous operation?

Answer (score 0):

This is called `auto-flushing` and is described (briefly) in the [official Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-flushing) (see the first bullet point in the first paragraph).  The reason Hibernate auto-flushes the `Session` is to ensure that the `SELECT` query works with the most up-to-date data, which requires the in-memory changes cached in the `Session` to be persisted.

The only (reliable) way to avoid this is to perform step 1 from your pseudo-code before the `for` loop.  This will ensure that the `for` loop only performs `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements and no `SELECT` statements.

If the data size is too large, you can process input data in batches, say, 500 records at a time.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the explanation.  You are still querying the database inside a loop where you are also making changes to data.  As I said, you must query the database before the loop and only make changes within the loop.  Any attempt to do both within the loop will cause the Hibernate `Session` to auto-flush.

Comment: If you disagree, please post the actual code instead of the pseudo-code.  I also think that you can shorten your post a lot if you simply post the actual code.